# Application development for meego & symbian with QT

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia, qml, meego

i'm beginner for mobile application development. i have knowledge of C language. i want to develop some app for meego ( Nokia N9) & symbian devices. i already downloaded QT sdk.now what i want to learn for application development. C++ or QML? as i told i'm very beginner for this languages.where can i start? pls help me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is starting by learning the programing language which corresponds with the framework you will use. Once you do that, you can start learning how to use the framework.

- Qt : C++
- Qt Quick : JavaScript and QML

After that, it depends on which plateforms you want to develop to :

- Classic Desktop OSes (Windows, Linux, Mac) : Qt with C++ is for you. You can use Qt Quick too but for the moment it is not really made for those plateforms. Moreover, you got skills in C so starting by learning C++ and then Qt may be easier for you since C and C++ have got lots of common points.
- Mobile OSes (Symbian, MeeGo) : developing in C++ may be harder on mobile OSes than on PC OSes. So you had better use Qt Quick with QML **and JavaScript**. Moreover, Qt Quick was made for development on mobile plateforms. Unlike Desktop OSes, you have got a real set of reusable components such as Buttons, Sliders, Scroll Bars... Those Qt Quick Components (that's their name) exist also on Desktop but they are not (until Qt5 and Qt Quick 2.0) as developed as their equivalent on Symbian and MeeGo.

Qt will always be faster and fluid but it is easier to code with Qt Quick.

You can also develop hybrid applications with both C++/Qt parts and QML/JS/Qt Quick parts but it is more advanced. This will be the next step. ;-)

Comment: I think, that with C background it is more advanced to learn JavaScript, than to make a hybrid applications with C++ domain model and using Qt Quick for UI only :)